# ReactJS - Passing props (state) to children of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, state, prop

I have a quick question. **How to pass state to children of children?**

If the parent has some kind of state, what is the best way in ES6 to pass this state not to its direct child, but to the child of the direct child.

I have attached of image of the layout.

> Main app - is the main component that consists of Header, Sidebar,
>   Content Area.
>
> Sidebar consists of - Sidebar Items.
>
> Content Area consists of - Content Items.

**Main question**

How can I by clicking *Sidebar Item* update the components that are in *Content Area*?

Please note that this layout has 6 components ( App, Header, Sidebar, Content Area, Sidebar Item, Content Item).

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only React way you can do this is by passing state and props from parent directly to a child. If a grandchild needs state or props from a grandparent, the parents must keep passing it downwards until it reaches the grandchild. React is unidirectional; from parent to child only.

So in your case the grandparent (Main App) will contain some state that will pass to the children (Sidebar and Content Area). For example from a parent component you'd pass state to a child like so:

```
<Sidebar someState={this.state.someParentState} />
<ContentArea someState={this.state.someParentState} />
```

When state changes in Sidebar (in your example, a click) it will be reflected on the grandparent (Main App). Since this same state is shared across multiple components (Content Area), each component with this state will be updated.

Now if you're thinking, "wow wouldn't this get messy if there are multiple children, with children that have children?". The answer is, "yes, it can!" This is where a state container (Redux, Flux, MobX) comes in. Here's why you'd use one:

1. Insert state directly to any children. For example, it doesn't have to come from parent to child, it can go from grandparent directly to grandchild. In Redux, you'd do this by simply using the `connect` and `mapStateToProps` function to connect parts of state to a single component as props.
2. State is easier to maintain and handle in larger applications. Try creating Facebook with only React by passing state down, down, down.
3. Separates state from a component. Since React is for "building UI interfaces" it's wise to separate state from presentation. For simple cases it's ok but as an application gets more complex it's not.

Consider the following resources for Redux (the most popular state container):

- https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux
- http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/
- https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

Comment: Great answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

If you're handling state in a more complex way, it may be worthwhile thinking about using Redux to handle state across the application.

This way, you can map the state to props using 'connect' and pass the state between components as required. Have a look [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components) for a bit more information on how to implement it.